# Is it possible to change UserName

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am trying to rewrite an old paradox application which has a long list of people. I would like to be able to import this list into the AspNetUsers table. Among other problems (id, password) is the fact that I would need to create a UserName and allow a user to change it when logging in for the first time. Is this viable?  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post your code and what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Why do they need to create a new username?

Can you make a 'migrate your account' link that would allow them to enter their old paradox user/pass.  They can choose their username at that point and this prevents adding a bunch of potentially inactive/dormant accounts from being created in your system (A potential security issue!)

Unless you are sure all the accounts are still in use this would be the preferred method, and it also allows you to easily disable (or restrict) the migration page at some point in the future after the majority of your users have migrated to your new system.

The migrate page would use a seperate user table (copied from paradox) that would have the username/password and also a flag to show when the account was migrated (to prevent it from being migrated more than once, which would be a potential security issue if the paradox users have weak passwords)

also you should add a 'paradoxUsername' field to the AspNetUser table, so you have a history of what the old username is and can identifies the users

Answer (score 0):

As per the capabilities of the Identity Framework this is completely viable. But you would have to manually implement logic to prompt/force users to change the username in the first login and give meaningful messages when duplicate user names are given.

Cheers,